# how can i show a derivation tree in haskell?

Tags: haskell, tree, functional-programming, semantics, algebraic-data-types

I'm working in a exercise that build a derivation tree of a while language. My implementation of while language is composed by algebraic data types like "Aexp"(Arithmetic expressions) "Bexp"(boolean expressions) and "Stm" (statements) :

```
type  Var   =  String
data  Aexp  =  N Integer
        |  V Var
        |  Add Aexp Aexp
        |  Mult Aexp Aexp
        |  Sub Aexp Aexp
        deriving (Show, Eq)

data  Bexp  =  TRUE
        |  FALSE
        |  Eq Aexp Aexp
        |  Le Aexp Aexp
        |  Neg Bexp
        |  And Bexp Bexp
        deriving (Show, Eq)

data  Stm   =  Ass Var Aexp
        |  Skip
        |  Comp Stm Stm
        |  If Bexp Stm Stm
        |  While Bexp Stm
        |  Repeat Stm Bexp
        deriving Show
```

After these algebraic data types, i created more algebraic data types to represent derivation trees of programs of while language

```
type  State  =  Var -> Z

data Config = Inter Stm State  -- <S, s>
        | Final State      -- s

data Transition = Config :-->:  State

data DerivTree = AssNS     Transition
           | SkipNS    Transition
           | CompNS    Transition DerivTree DerivTree
           | IfTTNS    Transition DerivTree
           | IfFFNS    Transition DerivTree
           | WhileTTNS Transition DerivTree DerivTree
           | WhileFFNS Transition
           | RepeatTTNS Transition 
           | RepeatFFNS Transition DerivTree DerivTree
```

How can i show this kind of derivation tree??

```
<z:=x, s> -> s'    <x:=,s1> -> s''
----------------------------------
    <z:=x; x:=y,s> -> s''             <y:=z,s''> -> s'''
    ------------------------------------------------------
            <z:=x; x:=y; y:=z, s> -> s'''
```

The expected value for each constructor looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Just do it recursively. How do you want to render the tree, text, latex, something else?

Comment: What's `Config` and `State`?

Comment: What have you tried and what problems did you encounter? Do `Aexpr`, `Bexpr`, and `Stm` really have anything to do with your problem of displaying `DerivTree`s?

Comment: @Bergi latex would be nice! The point is that i don't know exactly how to implement the recursive function to render this

Comment: @Cirdec `Aexp`, `Bexp` and `Stm` haven't anything to do, i wrote it to let you know what are these expressions in the tree. My problem is how to print the tree in a proper way to get a friendly visualization ..the kind of derivative tree of the image is a good target ...

Comment: If you're going for latex, it should be easy, as latex is just a syntax tree as well. Just transform each node into the appropriate latex command. Call the function recursively for child nodes. No, you don't have to start printing at the deepest node, it's just simple structural recursion.

Comment: Ok, i understand @Bergi can you show me the way to do it in haskell?

Comment: Can you tell us what the expected latex output is for each of those constructors?

Comment: Yes, i have edited the post @Bergi

Comment: That's still an image. Latex is text, isn't it?

Comment: I see a potential issue here: your states are _semantic_ (functions), so it's hard to print those. For a formal derivation, you want those to be syntactic (e.g. "s"), or at least with a syntactic counterpart.

Comment: Unrelated: why `Config` has two forms? In big-step semantics, only the first one is used. Do you really need the second as well? If you need it for the small-step semantics, consider using a different type for the two kinds of configurations.

Comment: @Bergi i know that latex is text, i didn't understand you. But i don't know the latext text to show the constructs ...

Comment: @EduGR: If your question is what latex syntax to use to create those images, it's off-topic here. You may rather ask at [tex.SE]. Then come back if you've still got haskell problems.

Comment: @Bergi , i posted it  here beacuse i need a way to do it in haskell , it doesn't mind if it's using latex or printing a string in the console.

Comment: @chi: you're right In big step semantic we don't need an intermediate config. It's just for a expressive implementation, in the semantic functions implemented only final configurations are returned .

Comment: @EduGR: Regardless, it's not a suitable question for SO if you cannot tell us what the output should look. Please show us what latex markup or multiline string you would like to have produced, and we can help you with the haskell implementation.

Comment: @Bergi i replace one image for the multiline string that i would like to produce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple example of using the [`boxes`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/boxes-0.1.4/docs/Text-PrettyPrint-Boxes.html) package to produce something derivation-tree-like. You should be able to adapt it to your needs without too much trouble -- either by producing a `Tree String`, or by using the ideas inside `pp` to produce a `Box` directly from your derivation trees. (I chose to use `Tree String` here rather than your type mainly to avoid having to figure out all the pretty-printing details of a data type with lots of constructors.)

```
import Data.Tree
import Text.PrettyPrint.Boxes

pp :: Tree String -> Box
pp (Node here []      ) = text here
pp (Node here children) = vcat center1 [premises, separator, conclusion]
    where
    premises   = hsep 4 bottom (map pp children)
    conclusion = text here
    width      = max (cols premises) (cols conclusion)
    separator  = text (replicate width '-')

sampleTree :: Tree String
sampleTree = Node "<z:=x; x:=y; y:=z, s> -> s'''"
    [Node "<z:=x; x:=y,s> -> s''"
        [Node "<z:=x, s> -> s'" []
        ,Node "<x:=,s1> -> s''" []
        ]
    ,Node "<y:=z, s''> -> s'''" []
    ]
```

Here's a sample run in ghci:

```
*Main> printBox (pp sampleTree)
<z:=x, s> -> s'    <x:=,s1> -> s''                       
----------------------------------                       
      <z:=x; x:=y,s> -> s''           <y:=z, s''> -> s'''
---------------------------------------------------------
              <z:=x; x:=y; y:=z, s> -> s'''
```

Comment: Thanks you!! That's nice!